# Why I don't have the "Deploy" button in my Google Apps Script code editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

[image: I don't find any button to deploy my script as a web application]

I have already a function called doGet(e). And also my developer can see the button when he log-in with his Gmail id. But I can not see the deploy button. Do you have any solution for this?
Or is there any way I can deploy the app script using a script or any CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the classic editor for Apps Script.

In this case, you have to go to `Publish` -> `Deploy as Web App`

[image: Publish]

You can also change to the new IDE by clicking on the blue button -> `Use the new Editor`

Comment: Or switch to the new editor